# Custom matching rules in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, match

Let`s say I have a set of custom matching rules defined something like these:

```
reject - Colour.green,
reject - Colour.red,
reject - Colour.yellow,
accept - Colour.*,

accept - Figure.circle,
accept - Figure.line,
accept - Figure.square,
reject - Figure.*,

accept - Number.*,
reject - Number.one,
reject - Number.nine,
reject - Number.five,
reject - Number.two,

reject - Greek.*,
accept - Greek.alpha,
accept - Greek.omega,
accept - Greek.delta,

reject - Letter.A,
reject - Letter.B,
reject - Letter.C,
accept - Letter.*,
```

* - any value;
Number, Letter,... are group objects and A, B,... are values from Letter group.
Number, Letter, ..., A, nine, alpha etc are all ids but for simplicity of the problem here I used dummy names/values ids.

The above rules are inserted into a table in this manner: src_obj/matching_obj/matching_value/rule

```
Figure  Colour  *       accept
Figure  Colour  red     reject
Figure  Colour  green   reject
Figure  Colour  yellow  reject

Number  Figure  circle  accept
Number  Figure  square  accept
Number  Figure  line    accept
Number  Figure  *       reject

Letter  Greek   alpha   accept
Letter  Greek   omega   accept
Letter  Greek   delta   accept
Letter  Greek   *       reject

Number  Letter  B       reject
Number  Letter  C       reject
Number  Letter  A       reject
Number  Letter  *       accept
```

The "funny part" is comming. I have a set of values to check if a restriction can be applied or not (if not return TRUE, OK, 1, etc)
All "entry" values have this pattern: (src_obj, matching_obj, matching_value) so

Letter, Greek, beta --> cannot pass (return false);

Number, Colour, black --> restriction rule does not exists (return true);

Figure, Colour, white --> CAN PASS (return TRUE);

Number, Figure, cube -> cannot pass (return false);

Letter, Greek, delta -> CAN PASS (return true);

Number, Letter, M -> CAN PASS (return true);

Figure, Greek, gamma -> restriction rule doesn`t exists (return true);

Is there any possibility to check an entry pattern with mysql? I'm not a mysql person so any idea will be great. I also saw that mysql have REG_EXP function but I don`t know how to use it in this case.

UPDATE:

Is this query a viable solution?

```
SELECT rr.fra AS STATUS, rr.* FROM (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT (r.matching_object_id, '.' , IF(r.matching_value_id = '*', '[[:alpha:]]', r.matching_value_id)) SEPARATOR '|') AS matching_rule_list, r.first_rule_applied AS fra FROM rules r
    WHERE r.object_source_id = 'Number'
    GROUP BY r.first_rule_applied) rr
WHERE 'Letter.B' REGEXP rr.matching_rule_list
ORDER BY IF (INSTR(rr.matching_rule_list, 'Letter.B'), TRUE, FALSE) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```